# Load resources located in seperate files inside the MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Goal:** Creating an XAML template which I can reuse and load into my main view. Is this possible? If so how? Ive read about the ResourceDictionary and came up with something but im not sure where to continue from there.

This is the XAML with my resource (kept very dumb and simple):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <StackPanel x:Key="myUnneccesaryButtonList">
        <Button Content="1"></Button>
        <Button Content="2"></Button>
        <Button Content="3"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here my MainWindow XAML where I want to use the above template and load it:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="Sample" WindowState="Maximized">

    <StackPanel x:Name="wrapper" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Edit:** Here is my MainWindow but the Window.Resource declaration doesnt work:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="Sample" WindowState="Maximized">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyDictionary.xaml" >
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel x:Name="wrapper" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: You are missing a trailing slash : `<ResourceDictionary Source="MyDictionary.xaml" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a XML Template then you should create a template

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myUnneccesaryButtonList">
        <StackPanel >
            <Button Content="1"></Button>
            <Button Content="2"></Button>
            <Button Content="3"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

then you could define a control to host it

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myUnneccesaryButtonList}" />
```

or

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myUnneccesaryButtonList}" />
```

Remember add the dictionary into the Resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="YourDictionary.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
```

or to merge it in

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="YourDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Adding the dictionary into the resources happens in my MainWindow right? I keep getting an error that the source property couldnt be found in the ResourceDictionary

Comment: it can happen in the Application the window a control, as long as it is up tree from where you want to use it

Comment: remember the value of Source has to be the URI of your xaml file

Comment: Added some additional information to my question. I just cant add resources to my dictionary. The syntax is wrong for the ending tag </Window.Resources>.... cant be right?

Comment: Firstly check your casing remember xaml is case sensitive source will fail where Source works and `<Window.Resources>` has to be inside the `<Window>` tag

Comment: Indeed, did you check the last code snippet? Ive done exactly that.

Comment: Indeeed it works now. So this is the go to way and I assume it can be also injected via code on run time. Nice.

Comment: Correct i would suggest using `ControlTemplates` if you want to style the controls or using the `DataType` property of the `DataTemplate` to set the type the template is applied to

Comment: I accepted your answer since I feel its more complete : )

Answer (score 3):

`myUnneccesaryButtonList` is not a template but an actual `StackPanel` instance.

If you set its `x:Shared` attribute to `false` in the `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<StackPanel x:Key="myUnneccesaryButtonList" x:Shared="False">
    <Button Content="1"></Button>
    <Button Content="2"></Button>
    <Button Content="3"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

..you could use a `ContentControl` to display it in the window:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource myUnneccesaryButtonList}" />
```

What you probably want to do is to create a custom `StackPanel` class that always adds the `Buttons` though:

```
public class CustomStackPanel : System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
{
    public CustomStackPanel()
    {
        Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "1" });
        Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "2" });
        Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "3" });
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:CustomStackPanel x:Name="wrapper" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: Don't think custom stackpanel is such a good idea, given that those buttons are just for example. You will have hard time creating whole visual tree in code for such "templates", in general.

Comment: That's what control templates are for but that's another story.

Comment: Very interesting. Is this still inside the ResourceDictionary? Im asking since you omitted the tag.

Comment: The "myUnneccesaryButtonList" StackPanel goes inside a ResourceDictionary. CustomStackPanel is just a class.